# TypeError: Cannot read property 'SHORT' of undefined

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, jestjs, enzyme, react-native-ios

I am writing unit tests for react native app using jest and enzyme. When I try to run the test cases I get the following error:

> ● Test suite failed to run
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'SHORT' of undefined
>
> at Object. (node_modules/react-native-simple-toast/index.js:7:23)
>     at Object. (src/client/components/Catalogue/events.js:10:29)
>     at Object. (**tests**/events-test.js:5:13)
>     at Generator.next ()
>     at new Promise ()
>     at Generator.next ()
>     at

The error is due to importing Toast from react-native-simple-toast. Without this import the test runs fine, but I need react-native-simple-toast in my component and hence cannot remove it.I somehow need the test to run with react-native-simple-toast in my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Platform, ActivityIndicator, Linking, Dimensions, View, Text, 
TouchableOpacity, TextInput, StyleSheet, Keyboard, Image, 
KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native'
import { Container, Header, Card, CardItem, Content, Left, Right, Body, 
Title, Icon, Button } from 'native-base';
import IconIOSback from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import IconMenu from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import axios from 'axios';
import SERVER_URL from '../../config';
import { Col, Row, Grid } from 'react-native-easy-grid';
import Toast from 'react-native-simple-toast';   //this causes the error
```

Kindly, help me resolve this issue.

Comment: did you look at events.js?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Please add the corresponding source code?!

Answer (score 7):

to get a way around this is to mock the property `SHORT`.
Create a test setup file eg `setup.js` and include the following mock

```
jest.mock('react-native-simple-toast', () => ({
  SHORT: jest.fn(),
}));
```

Ensure to add this file in your `package.json` under `jest` configuration ie

```
"jest": 
.....
"setupFiles": [
      "/setup.js" // location of your setup.js file
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have run the `cd ios && pod install` after the package installation.

It perhaps happening due to the existing cache.

- Close the app in simulator
- run again with `npm run ios`

Comment: how did you fix it?

Comment: Hello @samira this solved by clearing the cache and re install the pod packages. Some package installed to my application was broken.

Answer (score -1):

Install

```
npm install react-native-simple-toast --save
```

After installation .

```
react-native link
```

Then check this module is added or not , inside`node_modules` folder

Restart Project and run again

Here is the [Discussion](https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-simple-toast/issues/1)

Comment: I tried implementing this,however I am still facing the same issue.